# Java ~ Service Layer failed to call DAO layer and throw NullPointerException

Tags: java

Am i wrongly implemented the way to call DAO layer? The breakpoint is not hit inside the DAO method and exception throw only mentions about NullPointerException.Kindly advice. Thank You

**Service Layer:** 
    public class BookServiceImpl {

```
    private static BookServiceImpl myInstance;
    private BookDAO dao;

    public static BookServiceImpl getInstance() {
        if (myInstance == null) {
            myInstance = new BookServiceImpl();
        }
        return myInstance;
    }

    public List<Book> getBookList(BookDTO dto) {
        return dao.getBookList(dto);
    }

}
```

**DAO Layer**
    public class BookDAO {
        private BookDAO () {
            sqlService = Services.get(SqlService.class);
        }

```
    public static BookDAO getInstance() {
        if (myInstance == null) {
            myInstance = new BookDAO ();
        }
        return myInstance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never set value to:

```
private BookDAO dao;
```

in `BookServiceImpl`, causing this line:

```
return dao.getBookList(dto);
```

to throw NPE as `dao` is null.

You need to instantiate it before accessing it.

Comment: ya, you are right... i forgot it... and keep thinking what happen... haha... anyway.. thanks bro...

Answer (score 1):

In `BookServiceImpl`

```
private BookDAO dao;  // not initialize
```

and then you are calling

```
return dao.getBookList(dto);  // here dao is null.
```

Then you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: ya, you are right... i forgot it... and keep thinking what happen... haha... anyway.. thanks bro...